# mapping to list of object to model in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

My Question is How to **map list of object** in jsp using Spring taglib.

```
public  class Book {
  private int bookId;
  private  String bookName;
  private   List<Page> pages;
}
```

where Page is another class. I am sending object of Book class to jsp page and want to add pages dynamically from jsp page. I am using spring MVC project. **How can I achieve this**?

Comment: where is your controller class? You should return `ModelAndView`. And put your objects in it. And you will get with jstl from request scope.

Comment: I wonder why you added the `javascript` tag. Do you want to do anything on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user AJAX call for implementing this. You can send JSON object to server.i.e. page object to server.

Other alternative is that...
You can create dynamic text boxes using code:
This code is for dynamic input box creation...

```
function add(type) {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

tip: you can send list of pages through and by creating multiple text boxes to server

Comment: How do you achieve object mapping for pages attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL for each tag to iterate over all pages object on jsp

```
<c:forEach var="page" items="${book.pages}">
    <span>${page.anyAttributeOfPage}</span>
</c:forEach>
```

Assuming you have added book as model attribute like

```
model.addAttribute("book",book);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Ajinkya... but I want to add objects of Page from JSP page and hence initially list is empty... So I cant use forEach loop over list